# Changing HTTP Response file name

Tags: http, delphi, response, fastreport

I'm having issue trying to change the file name and extension created by my web service.

The current file downloaded is named **AAA** but my desired output should be **AAA.xls**. The file format is BIFF with an extension of .xls.

The file was generated in Delphi FastReport 4 into MemoryStream, then written into ContentStream.

I tried adding Content-Disposition to the request but the output file became corrupted which is only 5KB (originally 14KB) although the output came out correct.

```
    Response.SetCustomHeader('content-disposition','attachment; filename=AAA.xls');
```

Any possible thing i missed out to cause the file corrupted?

Comment: Please show a more complete [mcve]. What framework are you using for the web service? Adding a new header to the response does not alter the content you are sending, so something else is corrupting the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just got it solved. The problem occurs when it is gzip compressed. I disabled it since it was unnecessary for my small xls file.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use latest FR 6.6.2 - is problem still exists?